# How do i delete an untitled folder in Albums iPhone 5 PHOTOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

iPhone 5, iOS 8.3, PHOTOS

How do I delete an untitled folder in Albums iPhone 5 PHOTOS app?

Once again I am stumped, I can't delete a folder in Albums in the Photos app on my iPhone 5, 8.3.
From my camera roll I can select Albums. there is an album called `untitled folder`,
I select the EDIT BUTTON ON THE TOP RIGHT expecting to be able to delete it, but no.

I tap to the left looking for a red delete button, none, I pull to the right looking for delete, no, I tap the album nothing.
The only thing that happens is when I hit DONE, it goes back and becomes part the camera roll ext,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Delete photos and video synced from iTunes when you can’t access the originals.**

You can delete photos you synced from iTunes by syncing them with a new folder.

These steps will remove all of the previously synced photos from the device.

To delete photos that have been synced from a computer that's no longer accessible:

- Create a folder on the computer that you now sync with, and add a single photo to that folder.
- In the Photos tab in iTunes, click the box next to "Sync Photos From."
- In the pop-up menu next to "Sync Photos From," choose the folder you created in step 1.
- Apply the change.
- Uncheck "Sync Photos From."
- Apply the change again.

Your synced photos will now be removed from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you couldn't finish the question, but anyway you can't delete (from the iPhone at least) any of the folders that appear in your screen capture.
The "untitled folder" has been added through iTunes, and to delete it you have to connect your iPhone to your computer —apparently a Mac— and choose another folder or disable the picture sync altogether from there.

From the [Apple support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313):

> - In iTunes, locate and click on your device.
> - Click Photos.
> - Choose "Selected albums" and deselect the albums or collections you want to
>     delete.
> - To delete all synced photos, deselect "Sync Photos from" and,
>     when asked, click "Remove photos."
> - Click Apply.

Comment: Hello Jaime, I am now back at the Mac, day later. I have printed out your advise. Selected my phone in iTunes, clicked photos.I HAVE NO SELECTED ALBUMS

Comment: Hello Jaime, I am now back at the Mac, day later. I have printed out your advise. Selected my phone in iTunes, clicked photos icon.I HAVE NO SELECTED ALBUMS there i am unfamiliar with Ask, I wish i could insert a pic of my iTunes window to show you.

Comment: this did it for me:
Delete photos and video synced from iTunes when you can’t access the originals
delete photos you synced from iTunes by syncing them with a new folder.



To delete photos that have been synced from a computer that's no longer accessible:
Create  folder on computer that you now sync with, add a single photo to that folder.
In Photos tab in iTunes, click the box next to "Sync Photos From."
In pop-up menu next to "Sync Photos From," choose folder created in step 1.
Apply change.
Uncheck "Sync Photos From."
Apply change again. synced photos will now be removed from the device.

Comment: @jojoguitar Good to hear you worked it out! You can add your own answer (and accept it), it will help users with the same problem as you.

Answer (score -1):

Click on edit, then delete album.